# why I can not install packages from github?

Tags: r

I'm a beginner in R.  I have a problem in R and I hope you help me to resolve it. I want to install EGA and epmr packages from GITHUB. so, I used below R commands, but it showed error. I need these packages for my analyses.  please help me to solve this problem.

```
devtools::install_github("hfgolino/EGA", dep = FALSE)

devtools::install_github("talbano/epmr", dep=FALSE)
```

Errors of R:

```
devtools::install_github("hfgolino/EGA", dep = FALSE)
Downloading GitHub repo hfgolino/EGA@master
√  checking for file 'C:\Users\ramsa\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpGotfZq\remotes189861a473d\hfgolino-EGA-1a50a8e/DESCRIPTION' ... 
-  preparing 'EGA':
√  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... 
-  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
-  checking for empty or unneeded directories
-  looking to see if a 'data/datalist' file should be added
-  building 'EGA_0.4.tar.gz'

Error in .External2(C_loadhistory, file) : 
  'loadhistory' can only be used in Rgui and Rterm
Calls: <Anonymous>
Execution halted
In R CMD INSTALL
Error in i.p(...) : 
  (converted from warning) installation of package ‘C:/Users/ramsa/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpGotfZq/file189829151eca/EGA_0.4.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir) :
  skipping pax global extended headers
2: In untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir) :
  skipping pax global extended headers
```

With best regards,
Asghar

Comment: Trying to install the first package failed for me, but succeeded when I set `dep = TRUE`

Comment: it is a good practice to install practice with dep = TRUE even after doing so you are getting error do post your comment here.

Comment: @Hunaidkhan I heartily disagree with `dep = TRUE` being a "best practice" since it can needlessly corrupt running sessions. Sure, in some cases (like this one) it may be necessary, but it is _far_ from a best practice. There is _some_ expectation that folks delving into installing source packages from untrusted package repos should have some experience in groking dependencies.